# How to compare pandas DataFrames using set difference

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, set

I have `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,1],[2,2,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[2,2,1,1],[0,0,4,1]], 
                   columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1,1],[3,3,1,1],[0,0,1,1],[1,1,5,1],[3,3,1,1],[0,0,1,1]], 
                   columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
```

I've removed duplicate rows:

```
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

so each df is made up of unique rows. But there is some overlap between the two dfs:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     1     1     1
1     2     2     1     1
2     0     0     1     1
5     0     0     4     1

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     1     1     1
1     3     3     1     1
2     0     0     1     1
3     1     1     5     1
```

My actual `df1` and `df2` have shape of approximately (5000000, 23) and include int, float and object fields.

---

**Start EDIT:**
I want to create `df1_uniq` (what's in df1 but not in df2) and `df2_uniq` (what's in df2 but not in df1.

```
df1_iniq:
   col1  col2  col3  col4
1     2     2     1     1
5     0     0     4     1

df2_uniq:
   col1  col2  col3  col4
1     3     3     1     1
3     1     1     5     1
```

**End EDIT**

---

In set notation I think this would be `df1.difference(df2)` and `df2.difference(df1)`, but I get empty sets when I run that code. Note that comparing a single col in each df *does* work, e.g.,

`set(df_1[field].unique()).difference(set(df_2[field].unique()))`

returns `[2]`.

Another approach would be to loop through each df and if df1[i] equaled any row in df2, then drop the row in both dfs. But that is an O(n**2) approach and would take a long time.

Is there a more pythonic, pandastic way to do this?

Comment: Could you post an example of your expected output?

Comment: is your set element a row or a cell?

Comment: @DimaLituiev, for comparing a column, this worked: `A = set(df1['col1'].unique())`
`B = set(df2['col1'].unique()) `. For comparing dfs, this did NOT work: `A = set(df1)`
`B = set(df2)`

`B_uniq = sorted(B.difference(A))`
`A_uniq = sorted(A.difference(B))`

Comment: @Primusa, I added expected output to my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `merge` with `indicator=True`:

```
u = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
df3 = u.query('_merge == "left_only"').drop('_merge', 1)
df4 = u.query('_merge == "right_only"').drop('_merge', 1)

df3

   col1  col2  col3  col4
1     2     2     1     1
3     0     0     4     1

df4

   col1  col2  col3  col4
4     3     3     1     1
5     1     1     5     1
```

If the column names of `df1` and `df2` are different, ensure they're both made to be the same:

```
df1.columns = df2.columns
```

---

If the index also needs to be preserved, you can first reset it before merging, then you can set it after.

```
u, v = df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index()
w = (u.merge(v, how='outer', on=df1.columns.tolist(), indicator=True)
      .fillna({'index_x': -1, 'index_y': -1}, downcast='infer'))
w

   index_x  col1  col2  col3  col4  index_y      _merge
0        0     1     1     1     1        0        both
1        1     2     2     1     1       -1   left_only
2        2     0     0     1     1        2        both
3        5     0     0     4     1       -1   left_only
4       -1     3     3     1     1        1  right_only
5       -1     1     1     5     1        3  right_only
```

Now,

```
df3 = (w.query('_merge == "left_only"')
        .set_index('index_x')
        .drop(['_merge', 'index_y'], 1)
        .rename_axis([None], axis=0))
df4 = (w.query('_merge == "right_only"')
        .set_index('index_y')
        .drop(['_merge', 'index_x'], 1)
        .rename_axis([None], axis=0))

df3

   col1  col2  col3  col4
1     2     2     1     1
5     0     0     4     1

df4

   col1  col2  col3  col4
1     3     3     1     1
3     1     1     5     1
```

Comment: Thanks, haven't tried it yet but looks very cool! I'm wondering why we ended up with different row index numbers but the same values (I added expected output to my post). Did you do the merge on my original df's? Or on my de-duplicated df's? Just wondering if your code works without first dropping dupes (and if there would be a significant performance difference either way).

Comment: How can I adapt your solution to evaluate each row on specific columns rather than all fields, similar to how I used subset with `drop_duplicates`? BTW, your original 3 lines of code took only ~1 min to run. Amazing.

Comment: @KarlBaker Change `on=df1.columns.tolist()` to `on=your_list_of_columns`.

Comment: Thanks. `on=['col1', 'col2', 'col3']` runs but splits `col4` into `col4_x` and `col4_y`. E.g., `print(df_3)` `col1 col2 col3 col4_x col4_y` 
`1 2 2 1 1.0 NaN` 
`5 0 0 4 1.0 NaN`

Comment: @coldsp33d, I saw that you have a Pandas Canonicals series. I will be reading those posts in my attempt to understand the pandas wizardry in the code you supplied me. Besides that, could you recommend any book or tutorial to help me learn these methods and parameters? It's a goldmine, I see that, but just reading the documentation isn't giving me the insight and clarity I need to understand enough to troubleshoot and adapt the code as needed. Appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to compare sets of rows, you need to convert each of your rows to a hashable object, i.g. tuple:

```
set([tuple(x) for x in df1.values]) - set([tuple(x) for x in df2.values])
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your solution works on my toy dataset and is very straightforward. Time-wise, do you have a sense of how efficient your code would be compared to the solution from coldspeed? Also I don't really understand hashable objects and what makes them a necessary component of the solution.

Comment: I want to evaluate each row on only 3 columns as I did in the `drop.duplicates(subset=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])` step. How would I do that with your code?